# Flutter Paginated Data Table change footer color

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the footer color and managed to change some of it like the texts by changing text color in Theme widget but can't seem to change the color of icons in footer. Can we actually change it? Is there a way or is it just impossible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrowHeadColor in PaginatedDataTable for that